# What can I use instead of std::aligned_alloc in MS Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-alignment

I would like to use C++11's `std::aligned_alloc`, but unfortunately it isn't available with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

I'm considering, intsead, implementing `aligned_alloc` on my own. How should an implementation look like? The following for example doesn't compile, because it cannot convert from `void*` to `void*&`.

```
 template<typename T>
 T* aligned_alloc( std::size_t size, std::size_t align )
 {
        T* ptr = new T[size + align];
        std::align(align, size, reinterpret_cast<void*>(ptr), align + size);
        return ptr;
 }
```

Comment: 1) Do not use `new`. That calls constructors. Use `::operator new` to allocate memory. Return a `void *`, don't template it.  2) You'll need to allocate additional memory to store the original pointer returned by `::operator new`, so that you can use it for deallocation later. 3) Windows has `_aligned_malloc`.

Comment: what is the benefit of returning void*?

Comment: `void*` makes clear that you are returning allocated storage, not constructed objects. These are separate things that should be handled separately.

Comment: Maybe `std::aligned_storage` is what you need.

Comment: either `::operator new` or `std::malloc` returns a pointer aligned for any datatype.

Comment: @xiver77 except for SIMD (SSE2, NEON) and cache-conflict-free allocations. These requires 16-byte and 64-byte alignments respectively. Some platforms allow non-aligned SIMD load/stores but these need to be coded differently.

Comment: `std::aligned_alloc` comes with C++17 not C++11. `aligned_alloc` came with C11.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disclaimer: I didn't thoroughly test this code.

```
void* aligned_alloc(std::size_t size, std::size_t alignment){
    if(alignment < alignof(void*)) { 
        alignment = alignof(void*); 
    }
    std::size_t space = size + alignment - 1;
    void* allocated_mem = ::operator new(space + sizeof(void*));
    void* aligned_mem = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<char*>(allocated_mem) + sizeof(void*)); 
    ////////////// #1 ///////////////
    std::align(alignment, size, aligned_mem, space);
    ////////////// #2 ///////////////
    *(static_cast<void**>(aligned_mem) - 1) = allocated_mem;
    ////////////// #3 ///////////////
    return aligned_mem;
}

void aligned_free(void* p) noexcept {
    ::operator delete(*(static_cast<void**>(p) - 1));
}
```

Explanation:

The alignment is adjusted to `alignof(void*)` if it's less than that, because, as we will see, we need to store a (properly aligned) `void*`.

We need `size + alignment - 1` bytes to ensure that we can find a `size` byte block in there with the right alignment, plus an additional `sizeof(void*)` bytes to store the pointer returned by `::operator new` so that we can free it later.

We allocate this memory with `::operator new` and store the returned pointer in `allocated_mem`. We then add `sizeof(void*)` bytes to `allocated_mem` and store the result in `aligned_mem`. At this point, we haven't aligned it yet.

At point #1, the memory block and the two points look like this:

```
              aligned_mem (not actually aligned yet)
              V
+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
|sizeof(void*)|    size + alignment - 1  bytes          |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------+
^
allocated_mem points here
```

The `std::align` call adjusts `aligned_mem` to obtain the desired alignment. At point #2, it now looks like this:

```
                      aligned_mem (correctly aligned now)
                      V
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
| extra space         |  at least size bytes            |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
^
allocated_mem points here
```

Because we started at `sizeof(void*)` bytes past `allocated_mem`, the "extra space" is at least `sizeof(void*)` bytes. Moreover, `aligned_mem` is correctly aligned for `void*`, so we can store a `void*` right before it. At point #3, the block of memory looks like this

```
                      aligned_mem (returned to caller)
                      V
+---------------+-----+---------------------------------+
|               |  ^  |  at least size bytes            |
+---------------+--+--+---------------------------------+
^                  |
allocated_mem      value of allocated_mem
points here        stored here
```

As to `aligned_free`, it simply reads the pointer stored there and passes it to `::operator delete`.

Comment: Though I'm not sure why you'd do this when both functions already exist on Windows.

Comment: @user1235183 `aligned_alloc` stashes the pointer returned by `::operator new` right before the block of memory pointed to by its return value. Then `aligned_free` simply reads that pointer and passes it to `::operator delete`.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows it's *_aligned_malloc* and *_aligned_free*, which can be found in malloc.h.  The std implementation (of alignof/alignas) is in VS 2015.  It's not available in 2013.

Comment: Apparently based on my tests, aligned_alloc or aligned_malloc is still not implemented in vs 2017. So even in vs2017 you have to use _aligned_malloc as mentioned above.