# AVX2: segmentation fault when assigning to __m256i class member

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, memory-alignment, avx, avx2

I am currently refactoring an imperative C++ program that uses AVX2 primitives extensively to a well-structured class-based program. Unfortunately, I encounter an segfault when assigning to a class member with an AVX2 datatype.

I'm within WSL using:

```
gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)
```

Compiling with flags:

```
g++ -mavx2 -g minimal.cpp
```

A minimal code sample to reproduce the segfault is:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(int* arr);
        __m256i value;
};

MyClass::MyClass(int* arr){
    this->value = _mm256_set_epi32(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7]);
}

int main(){
    int arr[8] = {0x0,0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7};
    MyClass* m = new MyClass(arr);
}
```

GDB output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000080007cf in MyClass::MyClass (this=0x8413e70, arr=0x7ffffffedd90) at minimal.cpp:11
11          this->value = _mm256_set_epi32(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7]);
```

I already attempted assigning the class member after the constructor, same segfault.

Update: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566275/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-using-avx-on-an-array-allocated-with-new) is a related question, however it is not a duplicate.(Here: Focus on class members, relation to "new" only became apparent after initial question)

Comment: `new` doesn't respect alignment requirements greater than `alignof(maxalign_t)`, except maybe in C++17.

Comment: Interesting. Then I understand the error, thank you. Any suggestion for a workaround?

Comment: Use _mm_alloc or *aligned_malloc either with placement new or by replacing operator new and friends for your class. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612881/why-use-mm-malloc-as-opposed-to-aligned-malloc-alligned-alloc-or-posix-mem

Comment: @BufferFluffer: Did you try `gcc -std=gnu++17`  (along with `-march=native -g -O3` and whatever)?

Comment: @PeterCordes I tested this (or almost this) before. Unfortunately, [it seems](https://godbolt.org/z/GzsaPi) that GCC 6.3, while supporting a C++17 switch, will not actually generate a call to an allocation function with the correct alignment (thus, being non-conforming in this regard, as doing so [would be mandated by C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#14)). Starting with GCC 7.x, it seems to be working correctly…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: thanks, it wasn't 100% clear from your answer if you meant that, or if you meant that `-faligned-new` *without* `-std=gnu++17` was insufficient.  I guessed the former, but yeah I guess the OP needs a newer compiler.  gcc6.3 is "new enough" for most things.  gcc8.2.1 on Arch Linux does use aligned new: `operator new(unsigned long, std::align_val_t)` (which I can see from a link error if I compile with `gcc` instead of `g++` so it doesn't link libstdc++.)  So I know it's not just a coincidence that it happened to pick an aligned address and work.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, I just added a link to my answer, it seems that GCC officially supports C++17 new-extended alignment starting in version 7. If possible, upgrading the compiler would certainly seem to be the most ideal solution…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using avx on an array allocated with new\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566275/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-using-avx-on-an-array-allocated-with-new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has already been mentioned by Peter Cordes in the comments above, the problem here is that `new` does not respect extended alignment pre C++17. (See [[P0035R4]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html) which was adopted in C++17 to make `new` usable for memory with more than `alignof(maxalign_t)` alignment).

[GCC7 and later](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) supports aligned new with `-std=gnu++17` or `-std=c++17` (or just `-faligned-new`). Your code will Just Work™ and automatically pass the required alignment to `operator new` if you [turn on those options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373287/gcc-over-aligned-new-support-alignas).

---

But older GCC, including your 6.3, does *not*, so you will have to manually make sure to get memory that's properly aligned. There are a few ways to do so.

`_mm_alloc` was already mentioned in comments. On GCC, `_mm_alloc` seems to basically map to `posix_memalign`, so you could also just use that directly. A portable C++11 solution would be allocate a buffer large enough to accommodate an object of your class plus whatever space is needed for padding in the beginning to ensure proper alignment. You could then use [`std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) and [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to construct your object at a suitably-aligned address.

All that being said, no matter which method of allocating properly-aligned memory you choose, I would strongly suggest to encapsulate that stuff by providing allocation and deallocation functions for your class. The alignment requirement is a property of the type itself, it should not be up to the user of your class to know that, due to an implementation detail like the fact that it has a member of type `__m256i`, any object of type `MyClass` has extended alignment requirements, which have to be considered whenever such an object is allocated via a new expression. You should either disallow creation of objects of this type via a new expression, or provide the necessary facilities to make the type work correctly with new expressions…

A C++11 solution could look like this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

#include <immintrin.h>

class MyClass
{
    __m256i value;

public:
    MyClass(const int* arr)
    {
        this->value = _mm256_set_epi32(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7]);
    }

    void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        return _mm_malloc(size, alignof(MyClass));
    }

    void* operator new[](std::size_t size)
    {
        return _mm_malloc(size, alignof(MyClass));
    }

    void operator delete(void* ptr)
    {
        _mm_free(ptr);
    }

    void operator delete[](void* ptr)
    {
        _mm_free(ptr);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[8] = {0x0,0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7};
    auto m = std::unique_ptr<MyClass> { new MyClass(arr) };
}
```

[live example here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Aclass+MyClass%0A%7B%0A++++__m256i+value%3B%0A++++%0Apublic:%0A++++MyClass(const+int*+arr)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++this-%3Evalue+%3D+_mm256_set_epi32(arr%5B0%5D,+arr%5B1%5D,+arr%5B2%5D,+arr%5B3%5D,+arr%5B4%5D,+arr%5B5%5D,+arr%5B6%5D,+arr%5B7%5D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++void*+operator+new(std::size_t+size)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+_mm_malloc(size,+alignof(MyClass))%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++void*+operator+new%5B%5D(std::size_t+size)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+_mm_malloc(size,+alignof(MyClass))%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++void+operator+delete(void*+ptr)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++_mm_free(ptr)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++void+operator+delete%5B%5D(void*+ptr)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++_mm_free(ptr)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++int+arr%5B8%5D+%3D+%7B0x0,0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7%7D%3B%0A++++auto+m+%3D+std::unique_ptr%3CMyClass%3E+%7B+new+MyClass(arr)+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:56.09571892716385,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-mavx2+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:43.90428107283614,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: A made an edit which IMO improves the skimability of the early part of the answer and simplifies the presentation of your separate points, especially re: GCC versions.  Obviously feel free to roll back or re-edit if you liked your version better.