# std::aligned_alloc() missing from visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, c++17

Even though I did try enabling both std:c++latest and also c++17 separately, I couldnt use the std::aligned_alloc() function added in c++17. Is this real life? Did visual studio 2019 just flat out not implement an age old feature like this one in the standard(and a pretty important one too)? Can someone else confirm?

the feature I refer to:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) for VC++ 2019:

> **C11** - ***The Universal CRT implemented the parts of the C11 Standard Library that are required by C++17, with the exception of*** *C99 strftime() E/O alternative conversion specifiers, C11 fopen() exclusive mode,* ***and C11 aligned_alloc(). The latter is unlikely to be implemented, because*** *C11 specified aligned_alloc() in a way that's incompatible with the Microsoft implementation of free(): namely, that free() must be able to handle highly aligned allocations.*

VC++ has the compiler specific [_aligned_malloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2019) for memory aligned to power of 2 values, and see also [What can I use instead of std::aligned_alloc in MS Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133203/what-can-i-use-instead-of-stdaligned-alloc-in-ms-visual-studio-2013)
.

Comment: Couldnt they just bind the c++17 alligned_alloc() to the _alligned_malloc()? why do they not conform to the standard? visual studio c++ its basically another programming language by now. Do I really need to make a custom alligned_alloc() function that binds to _alligned_malloc() when using visual studio and binds to something else when using another compiler(namely std::aligned_alloc but hey maybe nobody conforms to the standard nowadays)?

Comment: @MatiasChara The std requires that the memory block returned by `aligned_alloc` be "compatible" with the regular `realloc` and `free`. MSVC's `_aligned_malloc` requires `_aligned_realloc` and `_aligned_free` instead.

Comment: Guess if I want to make my code portable I should use macros to alternate between using std::aligned_alloc() and _aligned_malloc together with their respective free and realloc versions(of course just making my own function with the macros to bind to these). right? Are the _aligned_malloc and family only useable in windows?

Comment: Those are part of the [UCRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/compatibility?view=vs-2019) which means Windows, only. However, the problem runs deeper than just adding some macro wrappers. In `std` you could write a function `char *double_string(char *str) { return realloc(str, 2 * strlen(str) + 1); }` and call the same function regardless whether `str` was obtained from `malloc` or `aligned_alloc`. With MSVC you'd need separate functions.